# curl command to post csv file

Tags: spring-boot, curl

We have a small spring boot application which has REST API as follows.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/import")

@PostMapping(value="import")
public ResponseEntity<String> importData(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file, @RequestParam("sType") String sType, 
        @RequestParam("CCName") String CCName) throws Exception {
```

This does not accept form data as it is not defined in the API. Any suggestion on how to send data using curl command?

Comment: add your curl command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at `-F` option in curl ([link](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html)).

For the controller that you have, the following curl works.

```
curl -X POST "http://localhost:8080/import" -F sType=sometype -F CCName=someccname -F file=@/path/to/file
```